# Why isn't my Windows 2008 R2 server hosted in Azure getting ESU patches automatically?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, azure, virtual-machines, windows-update, automatic-updates

I moved a Server 2008 R2 workload to Azure and should be eligible to receive extended support updates automatically as per this page without any need for configuration:-

[https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started/extended-security-updates#:~:text=If%20you%20run%20Windows%20Server%202008%20or%202008,Azure%20VMs%20if%20they%27re%20configured%20to%20receive%20updates](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started/extended-security-updates#:%7E:text=If%20you%20run%20Windows%20Server%202008%20or%202008,Azure%20VMs%20if%20they%27re%20configured%20to%20receive%20updates).

The server doesn't actually appear to have had any Windows security updates recently though.

I can see plenty of Servicing Stack updates as well as various .NET / Defender / Office components (which was why I thought it was all working), but digging deeper I have nothing that looks like a Windows Server critical patch, so unless they haven't published any recently (which seems unlikely) then I think they aren't actually being picked up by Windows Update.

Does anyone have any insight as to why this might not be working and what I would need to do to make it work?

Also, if anyone can point me at a security patch I should definitely have as part of ESU then I can check that too.

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer.

Scriv

Comment: Are these ARM or classic VMs?

Comment: They are ARM @SamCogan

Answer (score 0):

I ended up opening a ticket with Microsoft about this.

The reason is because we were using HUB licencing and the server licences were not linked to our Azure subscription.

We were able to resolve this with MS Support.